# Align Text vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a text vertically in a `DIV`. I tried it with `CSS` `line-height` property, but no luck.

This is my HTML -

```
  <div class="vertical">
     <h4>Content one</h4>
  </div>

  <br><br><br><br>

  <div class="vertical">
     <h4>This is Content Tow</h4>
  </div
```

My CSS -

```
.vertical {
    background: #8C3A0A;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Any body can tell me how I set these text to vertically center?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `vertical-align`.

The key is that it is applied only to elements with `display` set to `inline`, `inline-block` or `table-cell`. Moreover, the `display` property of the parent of these elements also has to be set to one of these 3 values.

And it does vertically align not the element itself, but it's contents relative to the parent.

**[Example*](http://jsfiddle.net/D4quh/)*, try playing with the `vertical-align` of the `span` element.

And also try changing the `display` property of the `div` and `span` elements.

I suggest reading w3c specifications or the **[Mozilla Developer Network article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)** for more information

Comment: How about browser compatibility of this example?

Comment: It is provided @ the MDN site. IE4+, Chrome 1+, Firefox 1.7+, Safari 1+, Opera 4+

Answer (score 0):

Change your `css` to this:

```
.vertical {
    background: #8C3A0A;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}
```

h2 default style.

```
h2{ font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0 }
```

[Default style sheet](http://snipplr.com/view/13337)

There is no need to use line height :)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aYJU/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But here I need to use height for my DIV. NOTE: I am using bootstrap

Comment: Updated fiddle tell me if is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/5aYJU/2/

Comment: Yes Alek, I can't use padding here

Comment: Last try for me http://jsfiddle.net/5aYJU/3/

Answer (score 0):

The H4 element is not align as you want. Add a `margin: auto` and it will solve your problem.

```
h4{
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9hLD/1/)

Comment: When DIV responsive, second line of the text is disappearing